# Kotlin Coroutines SharedFlow collector lost some data with gRPC Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, grpc, kotlin-coroutines, grpc-kotlin

I tried to use SharedFlow with gRPC Server side stream.

```
var sharedFlow: SharedFlow<T>? = null

fun createStream(): SharedFlow<T> {
  val stub = ServiceGrpcKt.Stub(channel)
  return stub.stream(request, header).shareIn(coroutineScope, SharingStarted.Eagerly).also {
    sharedFlow = it
  }
}

fun observeStream(): SharedFlow<T> {
  var stream = sharedFlow
  if (stream == null) {
    stream = createStream()
  }

  return stream
}
```

I get server side stream data by call `observeStream()`.

The shared flow obtained by calling `observeStream` does not collect data intermittently.

When data is lost, it is when the collector is attached outside `createStream()`.

I don't know why this happens and I don't know how to solve it. Please help me. Thanks.

I think it's because the collector takes a long time, so I simply received the data and changed it to do println, but it's lost.

I tested it as below because I was wondering if collect itself was not possible.

```
var sharedFlow: SharedFlow<T>? = null

fun createStream(): SharedFlow<T> {
  val stub = ServiceGrpcKt.Stub(channel)
  return stub.stream(request, header).shareIn(coroutineScope, SharingStarted.Eagerly).also {
    sharedFlow = it

    coroutineScope.launch {
      it.collect { data ->
        println(data)
      }
    }
  }
}

fun observeStream(): SharedFlow<T> {
  var stream = sharedFlow
  if (stream == null) {
    stream = createStream()
  }

  return stream
}
```

I attached the collector directly from the side that generates stream as above, but the data is not lost here.

Also, I checked which flow the collector refers to when running. I was referring to the same flow.

Comment: When you call `shareIn` you can customize the buffer size and how it handles backpressure. Look at the documentation for that function.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is `MutableSharedFlow` - something like:

```kotlin
val sharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<T>()

val stub = ServiceGrpcKt.Stub(channel)
CoroutineScope(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()).launch {
    sharedFlow.emitAll(stub.stream(request, header))
}

// then read from the `sharedFlow` in the usual Flow ways.
```